# How to localize WPF .net-core application with RESX

Tags: wpf, .net-core, localization

I want to localize a .Net Core application with .resx files. Can anyone give me a complete step-by-step solution? I'm new at WPF and .Net-Core. When I change the current culture in code nothing happens.
Here is my code:

```
<ToolBar>
    <Button Content="{x:Static strings:Resource.NewCustomer}" Command="{Binding NewCustomerDelegateCommand}"/>
</ToolBar>
```

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE");
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE");
        base.OnStartup(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Fwiw i prefer using resource dictionaries containing strings.  Used as dynamicresource.  More flexible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When localizing WPF application you have several choices.

1. Using native WPF's approach (with using UID), see: [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/wpf-globalization-and-localization-overview). This approach has drawbacks explained more in detail in the article, but generally saying:

   - it's not using resx (which is very natural for most of the developers)
   - does not support changing language at runtime
2. Using the resx's strongly-typed resource class generated by PublicResXFileCodeGenerator / ResXFileCodeGenerator.

   (see custom tool in the properties window in the VS for the resx file; PS: the second generator creates internal class, so keep in mind that it will be usable only in the same assembly where xaml being localized exists and only with WPF Binding, not with Static markup extension)

   This approach is similar to the one you’ve tried to apply, meaning in the xaml you use Binding (or x:Static) to the properties of the generated strongly-typed resource class. The drawback of this approach is that the generated strongly-typed resource class does not provide any notification whenever culture/language is changed. Other words, you can provide strings, labels etc., but they will be resolved at the time when xaml is parsed/loaded. After that it becomes fixed content:

   - does not support changing language at runtime
3. You can find on the market already available solutions for localizing WPF application using resx files, e.g. have a look: https://www.qube7.com/guides/localization.html

   - it supports changing language at runtime (UI automatically refreshes when you set [Culture.Current](https://www.qube7.com/docs/qube7.composite.culture.html#Qube7_Composite_Culture_Current))
   - the solution provides way to localize xaml that is supported in VS designer
   - approach of localizing xaml is similar to localizing asp.net: you may have local resources (resx per xaml view) + you may have global resources (resx that holds shared resources)
   - solution gives you way to localize view model as well (which is also something not rare to see)

   The full source code of the Resource markup extension you’ll find here: [Resource.cs](https://github.com/qube7/qcomposite/blob/master/Qube7.Composite/Data/Resource.cs)

Comment: I recently started to use qube7 and that's great. Thank you for your work @bgorski.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate. Feel free to provide feedback (here or on github), ideas for missing features etc. Also, let me know if you'll have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem using this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63731647/660753

> 1. Created a new Resource.resx. (Using Add>New Item...>Resource File.resx .
> 2. Copy all contents of the first file in the new file (Copy all three columns).
> 3. Delete the old file.
> 4. Rename the new file to the intended name.
>    6.  Don't forget to change access modifier of resx file to "public"

Also you can use this ASP.NET solution https://developpaper.com/dotnetcore3-1-multi-language-implementation-of-wpf/